# Oxyplot blurry in ViewBox

Tags: .net, wpf, oxyplot

We're using Oxyplot in our application. Our application allows to zoom the displayed content. This is done using a WPF Viewbox.

We use an internal resolution (for example, 300 x 200 pixels internally) and let the Viewbox zoom that up to the actual screen resolution of the user.

This works well with regular WPF controls, these stay crystal clear and are just rendered larger than usual.

But Oxyplot becomes blurry.

To reproduce this, take the latest development branch from Oxyplot, open the WPF Example and replace the Plot TabItem in MainWindow.xaml, line 126 with this:

```
    <TabItem Header="Plot">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <Grid Height="200" Width="300">
                <oxy:PlotView x:Name="Plot1" Model="{Binding SelectedExample.PlotModel}" Controller="{Binding SelectedExample.Controller}" />
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </TabItem>
```

This results in the following view:

[image]

Notice how the texts are blurred and also the axis tick marks look uneven.

I had hopes that the late High DPI fix would also fix this, but it doesn't (I pulled the latest development branch today).

I really don't know where to go from here. I'm mainly looking for ideas now. What could be the problem? I think it gets - partly - converted to a bitmap internally - but why and what can I do about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat, just started using Oxyplot and it's pretty solid so far, but this is a big issue for me. Why does it look like 1999? I did try `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"` and some others in my .xaml, but they were no help. I really don't want my project to have "that" look I associate with so many .NET projects haha.

```
UseLayoutRounding="True" 
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
```

Is my default to try to check stuff like this, but it doesn't really seem to be helping here.